# stop a forloop or function

Tags: javascript, function, for-loop, logic

I would like some help an advice on how i can get the for loop to stop 
after 20 numbers are drawn out to perspective div. I have tried a stop 
function/ clear interval , set timeout etc. What the best way to 
achieve  this as i am stuck on what is the best approach

```
enter code here 
  function lottoNumbers()
  {
    var lottoNums = [];

    for(var i=0; i <1 ; i++)
    {
      var temp =Math.floor(Math.random() * 80 + 1);
      if(lottoNums.indexOf(temp) == -1)

      {

        lottoNums.push(temp);
        document.getElementById('square' + temp).innerHTML = lottoNums[i];
                document.getElementById('square0').innerHTML = lottoNums[i];
      }
      else
      {
        i--;
      }
    }
  }

//test resizing div
function alterSize(type) {
 var targetDiv = document.querySelector("#square0");
 targetDiv.classList.add(type);
 setTimeout(function(){
  targetDiv.classList.remove(type);
  }, 2000)
}


/*
onload="setInterval(lottoNumbers, 3000);
*/
  </script>

</head>


<body bgcolor="lightblue" onload="setInterval(start, 3500)" >
  <h1><center>GENERATE LOTTO NUMBERS</center></h1>
```

Comment: Have a second look at the description of what a for loop consists of and how it works: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for

Answer (score 0):

It can be done with a for loop but it sounds to me like you want a `while` loop since you want to continue looping: while (not enough lotto numbers drawn yet).

```
while (lottoNums.length < 20) {
    //lottoNums.push(temp); and any other code you want to include in your loop
}
```

Comment: Thankyou Rocky I'll look into to it, much appreciated

Comment: Hi Rocky tried what you said , but could not get it to work :(, no errors in console when i tried to run it . i draw one random number at a time which corresponds to its div location e.g number 2 get place in div 2 etc here is a copy of my code from code pen.  https://codepen.io/anon/pen/RembEp

Comment: Looked over your code. There are a few problems but the answer to your original question is that you should use `clearInterval` to tell `setInerval` when to stop. See [clearInterval](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_clearinterval.asp).

Comment: The other problems I spotted are: 1) `var lottoNums = [];` should be defined global instead of inside the function otherwise it'll clear `lottoNums` array every time before you add another number. 2) `.innerHTML = lottoNums[i];` should be `.innerHTML = temp;`. 3) I'd recommend creating an `onload` function in your javascript rather than calling `setInterval` directly from `onload` attribute.

Comment: Thankyou I look into that and give in a shot :), it that for the forloop or while loop ?

Comment: Hi Rocky this is what ive researched after your commets but i cant not get it to run or stop as i looked at an example. new code is:     any ideas what i might be doing wrong ??           function start() {
  lottoNumbers();
  alterSize('large');
}
var onload;
function onload(){
  var count = 0;
  onload = setInterval(start,3500);

    if(count >21) {
      clearInterval(onload);
    } else {
      count++;
    }

}

Comment: I can't be sure without seeing the full code but it looks like `if (count >21) { clearInterval(onload); } else { count++; }` will only run once because it's in the `onload` function instead of in the `start` function. Also `var count = 0;` needs to be global (declared outside functions) or at least persist for multiple calls to `start` so that you can count up and know when to stop. I think I could help a lot more if we could do this in real time. Would you like to talk on Skype? I can talk this stuff through with you so it makes more sense.

Comment: where are you from Rocky ? I am from Australia

Comment: I'm from the US (Oregon).

Comment: I think the time difference could be an issue Rocky , just tried the break statement in a loop did not work either

Comment: ok cool, I think time difference could be an issue full code on code pen - https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OaJymR

Comment: `break` doesn't work because the for loop never reaches `i === 5`. You've set the for loop's condition to `i <1` so it'll stop looping as soon as `i` reaches `1`. Also `break` isn't what you want because you call `start` which runs the loop fresh for every new number you add so breaking early would just result in no new number. You need to do `intervalId = setInterval(...);` instead of just calling `setInterval(...)` and also do `var intervalId;` outside of any functions. Then call `clearInterval(intervalId);` from inside `start` if `lottoNums.length > 21;`.

Comment: No offense but virtually all you're problems could be solved with a better understanding of the fundamentals like scopes and program flow. I almost feel like I'm doing you a disservice to help you solve this particular problem without helping you understand the fundamentals and walking you through why your attempts haven't worked. For what it's worth, you might have a look at [this](http://worrydream.com/LearnableProgramming/)

Comment: If the time difference wasn't an issue, when would you want to Skype? Or would you prefer to stick with talking here?

Comment: Hi Rocky, I only have a laptop for skype, how will we do skype just message each other if so my email is mattsta76@gmail.com

Comment: Sorry, not until a few minutes ago. Just read your code and responded.

Comment: all good will have a look at what you said, just cleaning the house atm before i leave for work. much appreciated

Comment: hi Rocky sent you a msg on skype

Answer (score 0):

as rocky said, instead of using a for loop, a while loop would be more suitable in this situation, try using the following logic example and see how you go.

```
var lottoNumbers = 0;
var lottoNumbersCondition = false;

while(lottoNumbersCondition == false){
//your code and logical proccess goes here..
//and then your conditions will look like this
 if(condition to add lotto number = true){
    lottonumbers++;
 }

 if(lottoNumbers == 20){
    lottoNumbersCondition = true;
 }

}
```

So now the loop is gonna basically keep repeating without a numerical limit until the condition is met.